# how to add string as iTextSharp.text.Image in Pdf by. I was editing pdf on run time as

Tags: c#, pdf, sql-server-2012

```
 byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Patient Name");
                        iTextSharp.text.Image PatientName = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(toBytes);
                        PatientName.SetAbsolutePosition(Convert.ToInt64(item.XCoordinate), Convert.ToInt64(item.YCoordinate));
                        pdfContentByte.AddImage(PatientName);
```

But as converting String into byte and parsing byte into iTextSharp.text.Image it shows Error as

> The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.